# How to have one universally stored variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a calculator function where I have the Ans thing you see in many calculators. I want that Ans to be the previous result number, but if there were no previous results, for it to be set to zero. As of right now, Ans will only function as zero, and won't change to become the last recorded answer. I tried setting Ans to global, thinking it would help, but nothing changes when I comment global ans out

```
def calculator():
    global Ans
    Ans = 0
    while True:
        operation = input("What would you like to compute? ")
        listGroup = operation.split()
        checkOperator(listGroup, Ans)


def checkOperator(theList, Ans):
    if theList[1] == "+" or theList[1] == "-" or theList[1] == "*" or theList[1] == "/":
        performCalculation1(theList, Ans)

    elif theList[0] == "+" or theList[0] == "-" or theList[0] == "*" or theList[0] == "/":
        performCalculation2(theList, Ans)


def performCalculation1(otherList, Ans):
    if otherList[1] == "+":
        Ans = float(otherList[0]) + float(otherList[2])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[1] == "-":
        Ans = float(otherList[0]) - float(otherList[2])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[1] == "*":
        Ans = float(otherList[0]) * float(otherList[2])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[1] == "/":
        if otherList[2] != "0":
            Ans = float(otherList[0]) / float(otherList[2])
            print(Ans)
            return Ans
        else:
            print("You can't divide by zero!")


def performCalculation2(otherList, Ans):
    if otherList[0] == "+":
        Ans += float(otherList[1])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[0] == "-":
        Ans -= float(otherList[1])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[0] == "*":
        Ans *= float(otherList[1])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[0] == "/":
        if otherList[1] != "0":
            Ans /= float(otherList[1])
            print(Ans)
            return Ans
        else:
            print("You can't divide by zero!")


calculator()
```

Comment: Please don't delete questions and repost them. If an answer didn't work for you, edit your question to say that and show the new code you're using.

Comment: You need to either set Ans outside of a function, or create a Calculator class where an object instance can store your state.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ans = 0


def calculator():
    global Ans
    while True:
        operation = input("What would you like to compute? ")
        listGroup = operation.split()
        checkOperator(listGroup)


def checkOperator(theList):
    global Ans
    if theList[1] == "+" or theList[1] == "-" or theList[1] == "*" or theList[1] == "/":
        performCalculation1(theList)

    elif theList[0] == "+" or theList[0] == "-" or theList[0] == "*" or theList[0] == "/":
        performCalculation2(theList)


def performCalculation1(otherList):
    global Ans
    if otherList[1] == "+":
        Ans = float(otherList[0]) + float(otherList[2])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[1] == "-":
        Ans = float(otherList[0]) - float(otherList[2])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[1] == "*":
        Ans = float(otherList[0]) * float(otherList[2])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[1] == "/":
        if otherList[2] != "0":
            Ans = float(otherList[0]) / float(otherList[2])
            print(Ans)
            return Ans
        else:
            print("You can't divide by zero!")


def performCalculation2(otherList):
    global Ans
    if otherList[0] == "+":
        Ans += float(otherList[1])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[0] == "-":
        Ans -= float(otherList[1])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[0] == "*":
        Ans *= float(otherList[1])
        print(Ans)
        return Ans

    elif otherList[0] == "/":
        if otherList[1] != "0":
            Ans /= float(otherList[1])
            print(Ans)
            return Ans
        else:
            print("You can't divide by zero!")


calculator()
```

A global variable works perfectly, I adjusted your code. The variable *Ans* doesn't need to be passed as a parameter because it is *global*.